# Change center on google maps API3 on browser shrink and expand

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map at the foot of my site and I have it so that it centres properly on window load and also on window resize. Here's the code I have for the resizing:

```
var getCen = map.getCenter();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
map.setCenter(getCen);
});
```

The only problem is, when a browser window is shrunk or expanded the resize function does not activate. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here's a link to a test of the project: http://evinulrichpohl.com/trenholmetest

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right, when the window is minimized/maximized it is not changing size, and thus a resize event is not fired. Yet if the window is not changing size, why would you need to re-center it -- wouldn't it already be in the center when it maximizes again?

Comment: Ah, thank you Alex, I meant shrink/expand, not minimized/maximized. My bad I'm glad you caught that! I've updated the question.